# leaderboard command with mysql discord.py

Tags: mysql, discord.py

I am trying to make a leaderboard using mysql but I have no idea how to actually do it. I searched everywhere but unfortunately I found nothing.
The only thing I did was a sort query however I don't know how to show it on python. Advice?

```py
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT users.user_level, users.user_xp, users.client_id\nFROM users\nORDER BY users.user_level DESC , users.user_xp DESC")
    leaderboard = cursor.fetchall()
    await ctx.send(leaderboard)
```

```
[(13, 17500, 356536794646446080), (10, 10255, 488826524791734275), (10, 10160, 523967502665908227), (7, 2500, 572852913664163881), (6, 1000, 640479176280899584), (5, 500, 702691407034318920)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the format is the next one

```
(level, xp, member_id)
```

It's pretty simple, you can simply use a for loop

```py
for i, pos in enumerate(leaderboard, start=1):
    lvl, xp, member_id = pos
    print(f"{i}. {member_id}, level: {lvl}, XP: {xp}")

# Result
# 1. 356536794646446080, level: 13, XP: 17500
# 2. 488826524791734275, level: 10, XP: 10255
# 3. 523967502665908227, level: 10, XP: 10160
# 4. 572852913664163881, level: 7, XP: 2500
# 5. 640479176280899584, level: 6, XP: 1000
# 6. 702691407034318920, level: 5, XP: 500
```

You can put this in an embed, a message... That depends on your creativity really.

To convert an ID to a `discord.Member` instance

```py
# First you need a `discord.Guild` instance (you can either use `ctx.guild` or `bot.get_guild`
guild = ctx.guild

# Getting the instance
member = guild.get_member(member_id)
```

## Reference:

- [`Guild.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! But is there any way to convert the id with the user?

Comment: haha yes! Of course there is, editing my answer

Comment: I tried (I had found so many other ways) but it keeps returning `None`, I tried to convert the user id to int but it keeps returning `None` [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/799720337859674122/unknown.png)

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`? If not you can check out my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739779/on-member-join-and-remove-dont-work-how-to-make-it-work/65740995#65740995) answer

Comment: I did but it still gives me None [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/799737401286721546/unknown.png)

Comment: Now some updates them others don't [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/799767125010677790/unknown.png)

Comment: Hi! finally i found the solution and used `member = await client.fetch_user (member_id)`

Comment: Yes, that’d be an option, but it’s not the best. You’re making an API call and you could easily get rate limited, I guess you could limit the data fetched from the database with the LIMIT clause

Comment: wait, are you passing the ID as a string or integer?