# on_member_join and remove dont work. How to make it work?

Tags: python, discord.py

I don't know why but those 2 commands don't work for me.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    ver_Channel = client.get_channel(799666119787020289)
    await ver_Channel.send(member+ " have joined the server!")


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    ver_Channel = client.get_channel(799666119787020289)
    await ver_Channel.send(member + " have been left :(")
```

btw please write in basic coding explanation I'm a beginner

Comment: Hey there ! Can you be more specific about what you mean by "don't work"? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Answering these questions will help us understand your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is an intents issue, you should enable `intents.members`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default() # Enabling everything apart from privileged intents (members & presences)
intents.members = True # Explicitly enabling `intents.members`

client = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[How to enable privileged gateway intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents#privileged-intents)