# Discord.py | Undefined variable 'user' Error

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx, user_id : int):
        test= discord.Embed(title=f'A moderation action has been performed!', description='', color=0x90fd05)
        test.add_field(name='User Affected:', value={user.name}, inline=True)
        test.add_field(name='User ID:', value=f'`{user_id}`', inline=True)
        test.add_field(name='Moderator Name:', value=f'`{ctx.author}`', inline=True)
        test.add_field(name='Moderator ID:', value=f'`{ctx.author.id}`', inline=True)
        test.add_field(name='Action Performed:', value='`UnBan`', inline=True)\
        #test.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        test.set_author(name=f'{ctx.guild}', icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
        test.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=test)
```

I keep getting this error for the lines:

```
test.add_field(name='User ID:', value=f'`{user_id}`', inline=True)
```

and

```
test.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
```

why is that? Should I need to add anything in the second line? I searched on google and found out the use of it is like I did it but it does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined the `user` variable. In order to define it, you can get the `discord.Member` object by using [`guild.get_member(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member). Then you can use `user` variable.

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx, user_id : int):
    user = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
    test= discord.Embed(title=f'A moderation action has been performed!', description='', color=0x90fd05)
    ...
```

Comment: Same goes for here too, I tried this code but now the bot does not seem to work at all.

Comment: You probably haven't enabled the intents. You can check [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).

Comment: Yeah it got fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`user_id` is not the same as `user`, you also didn't define `user`, if you want to get a `discord.Member` instance you can either use the `MemberConverter` or `Guild.get_member`

Using `MemberConverter`

```py
async def test(self, ctx, user: discord.Member): # This will work with mentions, names, ID's, nicknames..
    print(type(user)) # <class 'discord.member.Member`>
    # ...
```

Using `Guild.get_member`

```py
async def test(self, ctx, user_id: int):
    user = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
    print(type(user)) # <class 'discord.member.Member`>
    # ...
```

#### Reference:

- [`MemberConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=memberconverter#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter)
- [`Guild.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member)

Comment: I tried it  but now it seems the command does not work at all

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: They should be enabled

Comment: Should be or are? It's important, take a look at one of my previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739779/on-member-join-and-remove-dont-work-how-to-make-it-work/65740995#65740995

Comment: Sorry for this late response but my router went off. So, I had a small mistake that I had not noticed in the code. It works perfectly fine now! Thank you **again**