# discord 1.0.1 discord.py 1.5.1 problem with getting the members in a voice channel

Tags: discord.py

urrently i have this but it dosen't work

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def vcmembers(ctx, voice_channel_id):
    #First getting the voice channel object
    voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.channels, id = voice_channel_id)
    if not voice_channel:
        return await client.say("That is not a valid voice channel.")

    members = voice_channel.voice_members
    member_names = '\n'.join([x.name for x in members])

    embed = discord.Embed(title = "{} member(s) in {}".format(len(members), voice_channel.name),
                          description = member_names,
                          color=discord.Color.blue())

    return await client.say(embed = embed)
```

it gives me this i can't figure out : discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you using the rewrite?

Comment: The server attribute is deprecated and was renamed to `guild` in rewrite iirc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `server` attribute was renamed to `guild`, (iirc in v.1.0.0)
2. There's no thing like `client.say` anymore, it's `Messageable.send`
3. `VoiceChannel.voice_members` it's also not a thing anymore, renamed to `VoiceChannel.members`
4. You can use a `VoiceChannelConverter` to get the `VoiceChannel` instance right away, no need to `utils.get`

Your code fixed:

```py
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def vcmembers(ctx, voice_channel: discord.VoiceChannel): 
    # The `voice_channel` var will be already a `discord.VoiceChannel` instance,
    # `commands.ChannelNotFound` will be raised if it's not found

    members = voice_channel.members
    member_names = '\n'.join([x.name for x in members])

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"{len(members)} member(s) in {voice_channel.name}",
        description=member_names, colour=discord.Colour.blue()
    )

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Note:** *You should enable `intents.members` and `intents.voice_states`, if you don't know how you can check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739779/on-member-join-and-remove-dont-work-how-to-make-it-work/65740995#65740995). Also I'm assuming you're using `discord.py` version 1.5+*

#### Reference:

- [`Context.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild)
- [`VoiceChannelConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.VoiceChannelConverter)
- [`commands.ChannelNotFound`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.ChannelNotFound)
- [`VoiceChannel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members)
- [`Messageable.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send)