# How to get the avatar url in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get the avatar URL using the following code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
@client.command()
async def avatar(ctx, *, member : discord.member):
    mava = member.avatar_url
    print(mava)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I get the following error.

> discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.

I have been digging for hours, including watching tutorials, but I have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: You actually need to pass the member as an argument when INVOKING the command in discord, e.g `.avatar @user`. Also you need to enable `intents.members` otherwise the `member` arg will always be `None` (check out my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739779/on-member-join-and-remove-dont-work-how-to-make-it-work/65740995#65740995))

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are needed. You need to change the `*, member: discord.member)` to `member: discord.Member`:

```py
@client.command()
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.member):  # No asterik, capitalize discord.Member
    mava = member.avatar_url
    print(mava)
```

I would also advise using `intents.members` as well.

In total, this means, when executing the command, you will do the following:

`.avatar @user OR .avatar [user id]`