# why isnt the new and old nickname changes shows up in the terminal

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a log that, well logs whenever a user changes their nickname however it appears not to work

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print(f'{before.nick}, {before.nick}')
```

Comment: Have you enabled `intents.members`?

Comment: How do I enable intents.members?

Comment: Take a look at one of my previous answers [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739779/on-member-join-and-remove-dont-work-how-to-make-it-work/65740995#65740995)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the discord.py intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work)