# Get the owner of a guild with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, owner

I'm trying to access the owner of the guild of using
`ctx.guild.owner` and I also tried `ctx.message.guild.owner` however both return None.
I want the owner to be formatted with their username first then their tag, like Bob#1029.
Is there a way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable intents.members?

Comment: No, how do I do this?

Comment: take a look at one of my previous answers, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65740995/13131047)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [on\_member\_join and remove dont work. How to make it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739779/on-member-join-and-remove-dont-work-how-to-make-it-work)

Answer (score 2):

To get this you need to first enable Member Intents on your bot.

Example Below:
[image: Discord intents]

and after you enable the intents you have to enable intents on your main bot file's code.
Here is what you need to add.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)
```

After that, your bot should have intents on.
Now, if you want to get the owner's ID, you can use `ctx.guild.owner_id` to get the owner's ID.

I hope this solved your problem, Have a nice day, and Best of luck on your bot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to enable intents through the Discord Developer Portal
[image]

In your case you would have to enable the one I circled in red.

You can learn more in the API [here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)